# Update views after device rotating

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rotation, position

I'm making an application which can be used in landscape and portrait. 
It's also possible to move some `views` in a `scrollView` (coordinates saved by `NSUserdefault`).

but I noticed 2 big problems:

1) when I change the orientation of the iPhone, my `views` reset to their first position. this problem is present only when i don't touch yet the `views`. If I touch a `views`, the other `views` change position when the iPhone rotate.

2) same problem but when I scroll. if I don't touch my `views` they change to old position when I scroll, and only once.
ps: after the problem, if I touch a view, all the views change to good position.

I hope I explained well because english is not my first language, so tell me if I forgot data.

Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine all your views frames here:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
}
```

**Here's an example to study the issue**

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var viewToMove = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 80, height: 80))
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    viewToMove.setupView()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
    scrollView.addSubview(viewToMove)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 800)

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPress(_:)))
    viewToMove.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

    updatenavigationItem(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Find", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(scrollToView))
}

func updatenavigationItem (size:CGSize) {
    navigationItem.title = "contentOffset: (\(scrollView.contentOffset.strings.x), \(scrollView.contentOffset.strings.y))"
    navigationItem.prompt = "frame size: \(size)"
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updatenavigationItem(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size)
}

func scrollToView() {

    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

    let x = self.viewToMove.frame.origin.x-width/2
    let y = self.viewToMove.frame.origin.y-height/2

    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(centerPoint, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Called, when long press occurred
func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch longPressGestureRecognizer.state  {

        case .Began:
            viewToMove.isMoving = true

        case .Changed:
            viewToMove.center = longPressGestureRecognizer.locationInView(scrollView)
            viewToMove.updateTitle()

        case .Ended:
            viewToMove.isMoving = false

        default :
            break
    }
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    updatenavigationItem(size)
}
}
```

> MyView.swift

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {

private var title = UILabel()

func setupView() {

    title = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
    title.textAlignment = .Center
    title.numberOfLines = 2
    title.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    addSubview(title)

    isMoving = false
    updateTitle()
}

func updateTitle() {
    let x = center.strings.x
    let y = center.strings.y

    title.text = "x: \(x)\ny: \(y)"

}

private var _isMoving = false
var isMoving: Bool {
    set (newValue) {
        if newValue {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
            layer.borderWidth = 2
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
            title.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        } else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            layer.borderWidth = 0
            title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        _isMoving = newValue
    }
    get {
        return _isMoving
    }
}
}
```

> CGPointExtension.swift

```
import UIKit

extension CGPoint {

var strings: (x:String, y:String) {
    get {
        let format = "%.2f"
        return (String(format: format, x), String(format: format, y))
    }
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="JYS-qU-rv4">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--Title-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_39229415" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="94" width="600" height="506"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="b1d-Ez-GEw">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="506"/>
                        </scrollView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="b1d-Ez-GEw" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="3nd-VB-tHp"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="b1d-Ez-GEw" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="F0H-xs-R6q"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="b1d-Ez-GEw" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="cq1-PT-JDa"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="b1d-Ez-GEw" secondAttribute="trailing" id="pen-6z-bT6"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Title" prompt="Prompt" id="cYl-MP-OqU"/>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="scrollView" destination="b1d-Ez-GEw" id="wWc-h3-6FR"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1447" y="580"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Navigation Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="TvF-x4-hHN">
        <objects>
            <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="JYS-qU-rv4" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <toolbarItems/>
                <simulatedNavigationBarMetrics key="simulatedTopBarMetrics" translucent="NO"/>
                <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" translucent="NO" id="EvU-Vd-zk0">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </navigationBar>
                <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="xj1-QQ-ihb"/>
                </connections>
            </navigationController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="pjs-pr-Pd8" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="635" y="580"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

---

### Your fixed code

I suggest you to create view1 and view2 programmatically.

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 150, height: 150))
var view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 220, y: 50, width: 150, height: 150))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.contentSize.width = 1000
    scrollView.contentSize.height = 1000

    initView(view1, color: UIColor.yellowColor())
    initView(view2, color: UIColor.blueColor())
}

func initView(viewToInit: UIView, color: UIColor) {
    viewToInit.backgroundColor = color
    viewToInit.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dragDrop(_:))))
    scrollView.addSubview(viewToInit)
}

func setupViewsCoordinates() {
    if let coord1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord1") as? String {
        self.view1.center = CGPointFromString(coord1)
        NSLog("\(self.view1.center)")
    }

    if let coord2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord2") as? String  {
        self.view2.center = CGPointFromString(coord2)
        NSLog("\(self.view2.center)")
    }

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    setupViewsCoordinates()
}

func dragDrop (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if let senderView = sender.view {

        let newPoint = sender.locationInView(scrollView)
        senderView.center = newPoint

        switch sender.state  {

            // case .Began:
            //case .Changed:

        case .Ended:

            switch senderView {
            case view1:
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(NSStringFromCGPoint(newPoint), forKey: "coord1")

            case view2:
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(NSStringFromCGPoint(newPoint), forKey: "coord2")

            default:
                break
            }

        default :
            break
        }
    }
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="sZy-5d-rmJ">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_39229415" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iH0-w9-3Vi">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="600" height="580"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="r4F-iB-85e">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="24" y="19" width="46" height="30"/>
                                    <state key="normal" title="back"/>
                                    <connections>
                                        <segue destination="sZy-5d-rmJ" kind="show" id="oqB-nQ-Cbx"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
                            </subviews>
                        </scrollView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="0JR-2o-xMa"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="H6h-8P-2lO"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="SXz-HG-hhh"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" secondAttribute="trailing" id="s9E-4S-nuH"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="scrollView" destination="iH0-w9-3Vi" id="y87-TR-x9X"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1064" y="532"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="jm6-I7-f2e">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="sZy-5d-rmJ" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="FVf-Ax-2ZB"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="LjK-dO-wuz"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ERa-Mg-7aJ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pYW-PU-huc">
                            <rect key="frame" x="269" y="285" width="63" height="30"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="63" id="5JS-Ml-DRK"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="UDb-RY-Nvb"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <state key="normal" title="start test"/>
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="show" id="PaJ-ee-tBZ"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="pYW-PU-huc" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="ERa-Mg-7aJ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="PFN-01-ccJ"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="pYW-PU-huc" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="ERa-Mg-7aJ" secondAttribute="centerY" id="ooK-Nd-fOP"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="9JD-Yr-djy" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="170" y="757"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this sample! As you can see, when you touch "find" and you scroll, the view moves to original position. idem after device rotating.

Comment: Every subview stays on own position. Only height and width of your viewController change. Look at viewToMove coordinates in running app. It always display origin coordinates in landscape or portrait orientation (you can scroll scrollView to find viewToMove). May be you don't want to keep origin coordinates of your subViews? May be you want to display your views in visible part of your scrollView after rotating?

Comment: yes i don't want to keep origin coordinates of my subViews. it's possible to move these views to personalize the page of the application.

Comment: So, I need to understand, how you are going to change coordinates. E.g. can you create two images of the portrait and landscape viewControllers  and show, how will subview change?

Comment: your example is good, 
when you touch "fin" button, your little view move to (-167, -328) right?
if you scroll, it come to original position and i want it stay to (-167, -328).
in my application, i can  drag drop with finger and save the new position of the view. (like your "find" button ) . 
juste wait , i'll make you a sample if you want.

Comment: Ok. But In my sample you can drag and drop too (I implemented long tap).

Comment: Don't saw sorry. In my applciation , the new position from drag drop is saved. so the position is like you just touch "find" button when the application run. if you scroll, it  back to first position. but if you drag drop one time and scroll, it don't back  to first position. you understand? (really sorry , it's difficult for me to explain this )

Comment: Just create several viewControllers in storyBoard with the subView. Create slide show for me) right naw I do not clearly understand you.

Comment: niiice thank you very much ( again !) .
Furthermore, the issue is very simple ...
And thank you for the code because mine is not very well.

Comment: You are welcome) do not forgot to mark my answer for another developers.

Answer (score 0):

ok do that:

viewController:

```
 import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scroll.contentSize.width = 1000
    scroll.contentSize.height = 1000

view1.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragDrop1)))
view2.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragDrop2)))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet var view2: UIView!

@IBOutlet var scroll: UIScrollView!



func dragDrop1 (sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let view_1 = sender.view!
    let coordonneesDuToucher1 = sender.locationInView(self.scroll)
    view_1.center = coordonneesDuToucher1

    let point1 = coordonneesDuToucher1
    let pointValue1 = NSStringFromCGPoint(point1)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(pointValue1, forKey: "coord1")
    self.view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}

func dragDrop2 (sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let view_2 = sender.view!
    let coordonneesDuToucher2 = sender.locationInView(self.scroll)
    view_2.center = coordonneesDuToucher2

    let point2 = coordonneesDuToucher2
    let pointValue2 = NSStringFromCGPoint(point2)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(pointValue2, forKey: "coord2")
    self.view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}





override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if  (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("coord1") != nil ) {
        self.view1.center = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord1") as! String)
    }


    if  (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("coord2") != nil ) {
        self.view2.center = CGPointFromString(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("coord2") as! String)
    }
}
 }
```

and main.storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="sZy-5d-rmJ">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="test" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iH0-w9-3Vi">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="600" height="580"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Db4-LA-Qvy">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="60" y="100" width="120" height="120"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.95686274510000002" blue="0.2470588235" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                </view>
                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EW8-HL-fjf">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="216" y="100" width="118" height="120"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.086176391690000007" green="0.40617938689999999" blue="0.9143629808" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                </view>
                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="r4F-iB-85e">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="24" y="19" width="46" height="30"/>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="5rW-5p-tHs"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="46" id="LS5-ww-xgF"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                    <state key="normal" title="back"/>
                                    <connections>
                                        <segue destination="sZy-5d-rmJ" kind="show" id="oqB-nQ-Cbx"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
                            </subviews>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstItem="r4F-iB-85e" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" secondAttribute="top" constant="19" id="nHI-Xd-HTr"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="r4F-iB-85e" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" secondAttribute="leading" constant="24" id="pPe-pp-LOR"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </scrollView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="wfy-db-euE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" secondAttribute="bottom" id="ExA-dx-c4N"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="FTi-D4-eT3"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" secondAttribute="trailing" id="GdD-Gf-1Hr"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="iH0-w9-3Vi" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="xGs-pR-FcQ"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="scroll" destination="iH0-w9-3Vi" id="IDr-Z5-Xrc"/>
                    <outlet property="view1" destination="Db4-LA-Qvy" id="LM0-5F-Wal"/>
                    <outlet property="view2" destination="EW8-HL-fjf" id="vrL-Jp-BkM"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="835" y="544"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="jm6-I7-f2e">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="sZy-5d-rmJ" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="FVf-Ax-2ZB"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="LjK-dO-wuz"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ERa-Mg-7aJ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pYW-PU-huc">
                            <rect key="frame" x="269" y="285" width="63" height="30"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="63" id="5JS-Ml-DRK"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="UDb-RY-Nvb"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <state key="normal" title="start test"/>
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="show" id="PaJ-ee-tBZ"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="pYW-PU-huc" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="ERa-Mg-7aJ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="PFN-01-ccJ"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="pYW-PU-huc" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="ERa-Mg-7aJ" secondAttribute="centerY" id="ooK-Nd-fOP"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="9JD-Yr-djy" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="170" y="757"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

Now, - run it
-move these 2 views to an other position
-click on "back" button
-click on "start" button
- scroll 
(-move again the views)

They moves to old position and i don't want it.
The same i you rotate.
now you understand?